# Sprite Kit test in xcode6 simulator

Tags: sprite-kit, xcode6, simulator, skphysicsbody

my problem is when I want to use "SKPhysicsBody" to detect which spritenode I'm touching, it returns "nil" in xcode6 simulator, the code is below.

init

```
    SKLabelNode *startLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    startLabel.text = @"Start";
    startLabel.name=@"start";
    startLabel.fontSize = 30;
    startLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-100);
    startLabel.fontColor=[SKColor blackColor];
    [self addChild:startLabel];
    startLabel.physicsBody=[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(80, 50)];
```

touch detection

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
    NSLog(@"%f",touchLocation.x);
    SKPhysicsBody* body = [self.physicsWorld bodyAtPoint:touchLocation];
    NSLog(@"%@",body.node.name);
    if ([body.node.name isEqualToString:@"start"]){
        NSLog(@"go");
        [audioPlayer stop];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"nameHide"object:@"Hide"];

        SKScene *spaceshipScene=[[SpaceshipScene alloc]initWithSize:self.size];
        SKTransition *doors=[SKTransition doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration:0.5];
        [self.view presentScene:spaceshipScene transition:doors];

    }
}
```

}

The `NSLog(@"%@",body.node.name);` returns `nil`.
what's wrong there, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to cycle through the nodes. In the last Xcode 6 GM this is different from Xcode 5. 
I had the same problem and i resolve in this way. 
In your case change your code to this:

```
    NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:touchLocation];
        for (SKNode *n in nodes){

 if ([n.name isEqualToString:@"start"]){
        NSLog(@"go");
        [audioPlayer stop];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"nameHide"object:@"Hide"];

        SKScene *spaceshipScene=[[SpaceshipScene alloc]initWithSize:self.size];
        SKTransition *doors=[SKTransition doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration:0.5];
        [self.view presentScene:spaceshipScene transition:doors];

    }
}
```

Comment: I have test it on my device(ios7.1), both methods can work, maybe in ios8 can only cycle through the nodes?

Comment: Yes, i think in iOS 8 you must cycle to be sure to pick the correct node.